# SQLPro or PostgreSQL SQL updating row based on previous row value

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I can't find the answer to the current question with my versions of SQL so hopefully someone can help me out.

I am using MySQL with SQLPro as the client or I can use PostgreSQL pgAdmin 4.

scenario I am trying to update a `null` value with the previous `not null value`.

here is my table:

```
primary_id  name  address  id
1           bob   123 main 100
2           jane  123 main NULL
3           mike  217 2nd  200
4           jeff  217 2nd  NULL
```

[image]

How can I populate the `null` values with the `not null values` so that the `address/ID` grouping remain constant down my columns?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the table, this will work in Postgres:

```
update t
    set id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.address = t.address and t2.id is not null
              fetch first 1 row only
             )
    where id is null;
```

In MySQL, this will work:

```
update t join
       (select address, max(id) as max_id
        from t
        group by address
       ) tt
       on t.address = tt.address
    set t.id = tt.max_id
    where t.id is null;
```

Comment: Hi I have been trying to get your solution to work and while it does work on my example table it doesn't work on the actual table....

My query is:

update family join (select home_street, max(account_id) as max_id from family group by home_street ) tt on family.home_street = tt.home_street set family.account_id = tt.max_id where family.account_id is null;

I get no errors but nothing is updated... account_id values look like: 0011I00000EWWDD

there are about 78 columns in the table not sure if that would make a difference.

what am i doing wrong?

thanks!!!

Comment: @DavidO . . . The addresses might *look* the same but still be different -- because the character sets being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating the table with itself. I inserted your table into a users table I created in postgres:

```
UPDATE users
  SET
    id = _users.id
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    address,
    id
    FROM users
    WHERE id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      address,
      id
) _users
WHERE
    _users.address = users.address
    AND users.id IS NULL;
```

So the idea is that I grab all all the non-null address and id groups (assuming address is always paired with the same id. I call this _users.

Match _users.address with your original users.address. Make sure that you are only updating the NULL users.id.

Comment: thanks! this worked like a charm in postgres appreciate the help!